# how to remove the default action using preventDefault in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

In my code's `else` condition I want to remove preventDefault() and submit the form.

I don't know to do this?

```
if(email.val() != ""){
            //check email
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/register/check-email',
                data: {email: email.val()},
                success: (data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data == 1){
                        name.css('border', '1px solid #248ea9');
                        email.css('border', '1px solid red');
                        $("div.wrapper div.right div.form form small.error-name").hide();
                        $("div.wrapper div.right div.form form small.error-email").hide();
                        $("div.wrapper div.right div.form form small.error-email-found").show();
                    }else{
                        //remove preventDefault()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: `preventDefault()` will not run in the `else` block since you haven't put it in there. Or rather, none of the code in the first set of `{ }` will run if your `else` block of code fires. It's one or the other. You can't remove something thats not there to begin with.

Comment: It's asynchronous, you can't do it

Comment: @AlonEitan `$.ajax()` is an asynchronous task, but why should it not be possible to submit the form in the `else` branch?

Comment: @Andreas Because the OP is trying to prevent something that is depended on the response from the server

Comment: just submit your form with jquery, add this `$('form').submit()` in else

Comment: Oh, I missed the _and run the form **submit**_ part - So to clarify: You can't prevent the event from the success callback, but you CAN submit the form

Comment: @Saad `this` should be the form, hence `this.submit()` would also work, hence no need to query the DOM again and no additional jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

An answer is never too late :)

My workaround is to add e.stopPropagation() at the end of the code. This somewhat resets the form to its initial state.

```
if(email.val() != ""){
            //check email
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/register/check-email',
                data: {email: email.val()},
                success: (data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data == 1){
                        name.css('border', '1px solid #248ea9');
                        email.css('border', '1px solid red');
                        $("div.wrapper div.right div.form form small.error-name").hide();
                        $("div.wrapper div.right div.form form small.error-email").hide();
                        $("div.wrapper div.right div.form form small.error-email-found").show();
                    }else{
e.stopPropagation();
                        //remove preventDefault()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you executed `e.preventDefault ()` in the button of a form, this will prevent the submit of the form, if you want to continue to submit you can use the `submit()` method of the form directly, like this:

```js
if(email.val() != ""){
            //check email
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/register/check-email',
                data: {email: email.val()},
                success: (data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data == 1){
                        name.css('border', '1px solid #248ea9');
                        email.css('border', '1px solid red');
                        $("div.wrapper div.right div.form form small.error-name").hide();
                        $("div.wrapper div.right div.form form small.error-email").hide();
                        $("div.wrapper div.right div.form form small.error-email-found").show();
                    }else{
                        //remove preventDefault()
                        // get form and submit
                        $("#form").submit()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

it dose not matter where do you put the e.preventDefault() at the or at the bottom it will work the same.

if you have the action on the form you can put it right after you start the block of submit function.

```
var submit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

i don't know about your case very much but you can use other methods like:

e. stopPropagation();

e.stopImmediatePropagation();

for further read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: It's inside an ajax callback, of course it's important where he put it!

Comment: as far as i see you did not you put it before making request.
and i'm telling you to put it before if statement. out side of the if block.
and explain what do you want to do what is your default action is it the form ?
i mean tell me why do you need the e.preventDefault at the first place.

Comment: But the OP specifically ask about a case where he want to put in inside the ajax `success` callback - This is what the question is about